# there is something wrong with this Jquery post?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

im trying to pass on the id attribute to the file.php, but its giving me 0 every time, when i try to insert it into the database, the javascript and the html is provided!

```
$(function() {
      $(".follow").click(function(){
        var element = $(this);
        var I = element.attr("id");
        var info = 'id=' + I;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: info,
            success: function(){}
            });

        $("#follow"+I).hide();
        $("#remove"+I).show();
        return false;

      });
});
```

html file:

```
<div id="follow1"><a href="#" class="follow" id="1"><span class="follow_b"> Follow </span></a></div>
```

p.s. it deos insert the value in the database

file.php:

```
<?php

$id =$_POST['id'];

msql_insert.........
?>
```

Comment: We need to see the rest of the PHP code. Just inserting data won't matter if your PHP isn't giving the right response.

Comment: that is the whole php script, the php script is only used to insert data in the database, but the id attribute i keep getting zero as the id value!! im not sure if jquery is reading it!

Comment: What is giving you 0?  You seem to be ignoring the PHP output.

Comment: the value of the id is meant to be number 1, but its giving me zero!!

Comment: Have you checked the Ajax request, which data is actually sent? (e.g. using Firebug)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not matter in this case, but the ID of an element is not supposed to start with a number.

Comment: @getaway - You have your <a> tag having an ID of 1 (one). That will blow up on you.

Comment: got it all sorted out, thank you, thier was a problem with the php script!!! thanks for trying